# Hadoop yarn task fails with no error message when there are more than one nodes

Tags: java, hadoop, mapreduce, hadoop-yarn

I am running Terasort of 10,000,000 numbers on the latest hadoop 2.7.3. However, the yarn tasks always fail except when there is only one NodeManager running in the cluster. Additionally, there is no explicit error message or exceptions in stdout or log. The only message is `Task Id: attempt_xxxx Status: FAILED`, and in logs the container or task attempt transitions from RUNNING to failure status suddenly.

The solutions I found on the Internet including disabling timeout or adjusting memory configuration won't work. In fact, for their problems there are error messages or exceptions in the logs, while mine is totally different.

So what is the probable cause of this issue? Any solution to it?

The stdout is as follows:

```
hadoop jar hadoop-mapreduce-examples-2.6.4.jar terasort terasort/10m-input terasort/10m-output
16/09/06 20:51:40 INFO terasort.TeraSort: starting
16/09/06 20:51:42 INFO input.FileInputFormat: Total input paths to process : 2
Spent 201ms computing base-splits.
Spent 4ms computing TeraScheduler splits.
Computing input splits took 206ms
Sampling 8 splits of 8
Making 1 from 100000 sampled records
Computing parititions took 902ms
Spent 1112ms computing partitions.
16/09/06 20:51:43 INFO client.RMProxy: Connecting to ResourceManager at brix-409b52/192.168.1.29:8032
16/09/06 20:51:44 INFO mapreduce.JobSubmitter: number of splits:8
16/09/06 20:51:44 INFO mapreduce.JobSubmitter: Submitting tokens for job: job_1473165713268_0002
16/09/06 20:51:44 INFO impl.YarnClientImpl: Submitted application application_1473165713268_0002
16/09/06 20:51:44 INFO mapreduce.Job: The url to track the job: http://brix-409b52:8088/proxy/application_1473165713268_0002/
16/09/06 20:51:44 INFO mapreduce.Job: Running job: job_1473165713268_0002
16/09/06 20:51:55 INFO mapreduce.Job: Job job_1473165713268_0002 running in uber mode : false
16/09/06 20:51:55 INFO mapreduce.Job:  map 0% reduce 0%
16/09/06 20:52:11 INFO mapreduce.Job: Task Id : attempt_1473165713268_0002_m_000003_0, Status : FAILED
16/09/06 20:52:12 INFO mapreduce.Job:  map 4% reduce 0%
16/09/06 20:52:12 INFO mapreduce.Job: Task Id : attempt_1473165713268_0002_m_000000_0, Status : FAILED
16/09/06 20:52:13 INFO mapreduce.Job: Task Id : attempt_1473165713268_0002_m_000001_0, Status : FAILED
16/09/06 20:52:15 INFO mapreduce.Job:  map 6% reduce 0%
16/09/06 20:52:18 INFO mapreduce.Job:  map 8% reduce 0%
16/09/06 20:52:23 INFO mapreduce.Job:  map 13% reduce 0%
16/09/06 20:52:26 INFO mapreduce.Job: Task Id : attempt_1473165713268_0002_m_000003_1, Status : FAILED
16/09/06 20:52:28 INFO mapreduce.Job: Task Id : attempt_1473165713268_0002_m_000000_1, Status : FAILED
16/09/06 20:52:29 INFO mapreduce.Job: Task Id : attempt_1473165713268_0002_m_000001_1, Status : FAILED
16/09/06 20:52:32 INFO mapreduce.Job:  map 21% reduce 0%
16/09/06 20:52:35 INFO mapreduce.Job:  map 25% reduce 0%
16/09/06 20:52:42 INFO mapreduce.Job: Task Id : attempt_1473165713268_0002_m_000003_2, Status : FAILED
16/09/06 20:52:44 INFO mapreduce.Job: Task Id : attempt_1473165713268_0002_m_000005_0, Status : FAILED
16/09/06 20:52:44 INFO mapreduce.Job: Task Id : attempt_1473165713268_0002_m_000000_2, Status : FAILED
16/09/06 20:52:45 INFO mapreduce.Job:  map 29% reduce 0%
16/09/06 20:52:48 INFO mapreduce.Job:  map 31% reduce 0%
16/09/06 20:52:51 INFO mapreduce.Job:  map 32% reduce 0%
16/09/06 20:52:54 INFO mapreduce.Job:  map 33% reduce 0%
16/09/06 20:52:55 INFO mapreduce.Job: Task Id : attempt_1473165713268_0002_r_000000_0, Status : FAILED
16/09/06 20:52:56 INFO mapreduce.Job:  map 38% reduce 0%
16/09/06 20:52:59 INFO mapreduce.Job:  map 100% reduce 100%
16/09/06 20:53:00 INFO mapreduce.Job: Job job_1473165713268_0002 failed with state FAILED due to: Task failed task_1473165713268_0002_m_000003
Job failed as tasks failed. failedMaps:1 failedReduces:0

16/09/06 20:53:01 INFO mapreduce.Job: Counters: 42
    File System Counters
        FILE: Number of bytes read=418759260
        FILE: Number of bytes written=837878859
        FILE: Number of read operations=0
        FILE: Number of large read operations=0
        FILE: Number of write operations=0
        HDFS: Number of bytes read=402653508
        HDFS: Number of bytes written=0
        HDFS: Number of read operations=9
        HDFS: Number of large read operations=0
        HDFS: Number of write operations=0
```

Also here is part of the detailed NodeManager log that shows the failure of a container or task attempt:

```
2016-09-06 21:05:33,015 INFO org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.containermanager.application.ApplicationImpl: Adding container_1473165713268_0003_01_000012 to application application_1473165713268_0003
2016-09-06 21:05:33,015 INFO org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.containermanager.container.ContainerImpl: Container container_1473165713268_0003_01_000012 transitioned from NEW to LOCALIZING
2016-09-06 21:05:33,015 INFO org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.containermanager.AuxServices: Got event CONTAINER_INIT for appId application_1473165713268_0003
2016-09-06 21:05:33,015 INFO org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.containermanager.AuxServices: Got event APPLICATION_INIT for appId application_1473165713268_0003
2016-09-06 21:05:33,015 INFO org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.containermanager.AuxServices: Got APPLICATION_INIT for service mapreduce_shuffle
2016-09-06 21:05:33,015 INFO org.apache.hadoop.mapred.ShuffleHandler: Added token for job_1473165713268_0003
2016-09-06 21:05:33,016 INFO org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.containermanager.container.ContainerImpl: Container container_1473165713268_0003_01_000012 transitioned from LOCALIZING to LOCALIZED
2016-09-06 21:05:33,027 INFO SecurityLogger.org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server: Auth successful for appattempt_1473165713268_0003_000001 (auth:SIMPLE)
2016-09-06 21:05:33,036 INFO org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.containermanager.ContainerManagerImpl: Stopping container with container Id: container_1473165713268_0003_01_000012
2016-09-06 21:05:33,036 INFO org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.NMAuditLogger: USER=excelle08    IP=127.0.0.1    OPERATION=Stop Container Request        TARGET=ContainerManageImpl      RESULT=SUCCESS  APPID=application_1473165713268_0003    CONTAINERID=container_1473165713268_0003_01_000012
2016-09-06 21:05:33,039 INFO org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.containermanager.container.ContainerImpl: Container container_1473165713268_0003_01_000012 transitioned from LOCALIZED to KILLING
2016-09-06 21:05:33,039 INFO org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.containermanager.launcher.ContainerLaunch: Cleaning up container container_1473165713268_0003_01_000012
2016-09-06 21:05:33,039 INFO org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.containermanager.launcher.ContainerLaunch: Container container_1473165713268_0003_01_000012 not launched. No cleanup needed to be done
2016-09-06 21:05:33,055 INFO org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.containermanager.launcher.ContainerLaunch: Container container_1473165713268_0003_01_000012 not launched as cleanup already called
2016-09-06 21:05:33,060 INFO org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.containermanager.container.ContainerImpl: Container container_1473165713268_0003_01_000012 transitioned from KILLING to CONTAINER_CLEANEDUP_AFTER_KILL
2016-09-06 21:05:33,061 INFO org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.NMAuditLogger: USER=excelle08    OPERATION=Container Finished - Killed   TARGET=ContainerImpl    RESULT=SUCCESS  APPID=application_1473165713268_0003    CONTAINERID=container_1473165713268_0003_01_000012
2016-09-06 21:05:33,061 INFO org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.containermanager.container.ContainerImpl: Container container_1473165713268_0003_01_000012 transitioned from CONTAINER_CLEANEDUP_AFTER_KILL to DONE
2016-09-06 21:05:33,061 INFO org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.containermanager.application.ApplicationImpl: Removing container_1473165713268_0003_01_000012 from application application_1473165713268_0003
2016-09-06 21:05:33,061 INFO org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.containermanager.AuxServices: Got event CONTAINER_STOP for appId application_1473165713268_0003
2016-09-06 21:05:34,064 INFO org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.NodeStatusUpdaterImpl: Removed completed containers from NM context: [container_1473165713268_0003_01_000011]
2016-09-06 21:05:34,473 INFO org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.containermanager.monitor.ContainersMonitorImpl: Stopping resource-monitoring for container_1473165713268_0003_01_000011
2016-09-06 21:05:34,474 INFO org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.containermanager.monitor.ContainersMonitorImpl: Stopping resource-monitoring for container_1473165713268_0003_01_000012
2016-09-06 21:05:34,481 INFO org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.containermanager.monitor.ContainersMonitorImpl: Memory usage of ProcessTree 14187 for container-id container_1473165713268_0003_01_000001: 291.4 MB of 2 GB physical memory used; 2.7 GB of 6 GB virtual memory used
2016-09-06 21:05:35,067 INFO org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.NodeStatusUpdaterImpl: Removed completed containers from NM context: [container_1473165713268_0003_01_000012]
```

Comment: Try to find something in /var/log/messages and dmesg. It seems that operation system killed the container process.

Comment: But there is no /var/log/messages in the system. Also dmesg didn't print any new information.

Comment: Your system is Ubuntu? If it is,  try /var/log/syslog

Comment: In fact it's archlinux